# Why do we need to diversify our food sources to live healthy, where other animals live happy on one source?

Tags: nutrition

We read about eating different food to get all vitamins and minerals our body need, and often you find people fail to get the daily amount of a certain thing.
I wonder why we humans need to do this where other animal live fine on grass only or leafs only

Comment: All organisms have some dietary requirements. Many organisms cannot synthesize everything they need from basic compounds and they have to obtain them from other organisms. This is not specific to humans.

Comment: OK, What about sheep as an example, do they eat anything other than grass? Does grass has all the nutrition they need?

Comment: Strictly speaking, humans, at least infants, can live on a single food source - milk. The current recommendations about eating something from all food groups may be exaggerating. Several studies have shown that vegans are not of greater risk of developing disease than omnivores, for example.

Comment: You say that like grass or leaves are easy to live off of, animals that live off these materials have highly specialized digestive systems to extract enough nutrients from it. Also note these herbivores are more than willing to eat things like meat and eggs when they can get it. Deer will stomp nesting birds to death and eat them. They can improve their health by obtaining these nutrient rich sources.

Comment: Also, grass and leaves are not simple things, but are quite diverse.  E.g. many humans happily consume the leaves of lettuce & cabbage (and other sorts like grape leaves in regional cuisines: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_leaf_vegetables ), but would be poisoned by eating the leaves of say rhubarb.